# How to add the opportunity Owner as a CC Recipient in Docusign for Salesforce V 7.0?

Tags: custom-button, docusign

I have created a "Send with Docusign" button in SF using the new "Docusign Envelope Configuration" tool available in Version 7.0. I am tryng to add a the opportunity owner as one of the Recipients with no Success. Below you have the code of my button and what I'm trying to add.

Custom button code:

```
{!URLFOR("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope",null, [sId=Opportunity.Id,ecId="a0Q2G00000H4fyiUAB"])}
```

Trying to add a new CRL with no success

```
CRL = 'Email~'+encodeURIComponent('{!Opportunity.OwnerEmail};
Role~CarbonCopy;
FirstName{!Opportunity.OwnerFirstName};
LastName{!Opportunity.OwnerLastName};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this resolved, creating a new button from scratch and adding a CRL pulling the information from the Opportunity Owner. Custom URL button code below.

```
{!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope', null, [ 
SourceID = Opportunity.Id, 
CCRM = 'Primary Guarantor~Signer 1;Signer 2~Signer 2', 
CCTM = ' Primary Guarantor~Signer;Signer 2~Carbon copy;AE~Receives a Copy', 
CRL = 'Email~' + Opportunity.OwnerEmail + ';FirstName~' + Opportunity.OwnerFirstName 
+ ';LastName~' + Opportunity.OwnerLastName + ';Role~TestRole;RoutingOrder~1', 
OCO = 'Preview', 
LA = '1' 
] 
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax for the CRL Param:

```
CRL = 'Email~' + Quote.Contact_Email__c + ';LastName~'+ Quote.Contact_Name__c +';Role~Signer 1;,Email~'+ User.Email + ';LastName~'+ User.Name + ';Role~Signer 2',
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I used.